# Find the quadratic equation, given three points on the parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> Given that $f(x)=a(x-b)^2+c$, and that $f(1)=f(5)=-1$ and $f(0)=-11$, find the values of $a,b$,and $c$.

I found the axis of symmetry is $3$, because $f$ has the same value at $1$ and $5$, and $(1+5)/2=3$. Therefore $b=3$. How to find $a$ and $c$?

Comment: You can have two equations and two variables. What do you get when you try solving them?

Comment: I have the y int, and two coordinates. I just can't seem to find any of the other 2 values.

Comment: I also don't know how to create the two equations that would help in a system of equations.

Comment: Yes I know the B value by adding 5 and 1, and then dividing to get 3. I just cannot find the C value in order to find A.

Answer (score 1):

You have found $b$ correctly as 3. I.e. $f(x)=a(x-3)^2+c=0$.

From this point you could solve simultaneously to get $a$ and $c$. I.e. solving:

$$f(1)=a(1-3)^2+c=-1$$
$$f(0)=a(0-3)^2+c=-11$$

But there is an even easier way thinking about it graphically:

As you have two points with the same y-value we could also express the quadratic as: $f(x)=a(x-1)(x-5)-1$. Now we only need to solve one equation in one variable:

$$f(0)=a(0-1)(0-5)-1=-11$$
$$5a-1=-11$$
$$5a=-10$$
$$a=-2$$
So the equation is:
$$f(x)=-2(x-1)(x-5)-1$$
$$f(x)=-2(x-3+2)(x-3-2)-1$$
$$f(x)=-2((x-3)^2-4)-1$$
$$f(x)=-2(x-3)^2+7$$